# from log with regex extracted values fail correct insertion into sqlite table

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, iteration

Problem with storing extracted values in SQLite - How to adress or index list of values for proper insertion into table.

The Regex works fine:

input logging data looks like:

0.0.0(06026104)
1.6.1(0.1501)(1011111000)
1.6.1*32(0.1446)(1010190800)
1.8.1(02484.825)
1.8.1*32(02449.574)

correct regex output:

06026104
0.1501
02484.796

```
with open("usage.log") as fp:
  for line in fp:
    match = re.match(r'(0\.0\.0|1\.6\.1|1\.8\.1)\(([0-9\.]+)', line)
    if not match: continue
    version, value = match.groups()
    mylist.append(value)
for item in mylist:
   t = (item)
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO energielog(sernr) values (?)', [t])
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO energielog(peak) values (?)', [t])
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO energielog(kwh) values (?)', [t])
```

How can I achieve the proper line by line read into SQLite?

Now each line gets fed into table wrong: 06026104 is in line 1 row 1 and line 2 row 2 and line 3 row 3. Second value is only in line 4 row 1 and line 5 row 2 so forth..

For example, if I let print t[0:3], the output is:

060
0.01
024

did it make rows out of it? How can I feed value 1 (06026104) into table row "sernr" and value2 (0.1501) into table row "peak" ..

Comment: Please, explain a bit more what you want to do, what you want your regex to match, etc. Your examples give away very little information.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fp:
        match = re.search(r'(0\.0\.0|1\.6\.1|1\.8\.1)\(([0-9\.]+)', line)
        if match: 
            version,value = match.groups() 
            extrakt.append(value)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO energielog (sernr, peak, kwh) values (?, ?, ?)', extrakt)
```

that works out

Comment: I was sloppy with syntax, especially whitespaces  were missing